# Upload any files with Alamofire 4

Tags: ios, swift, file, alamofire, send

I have an app, where user can import any type of files as many as he wants and after that he should be able to send them to server. User can attach picked images from gallery, taken photos from camera, and any files using **UIDocumentPickerViewController**

This is the point where I'm struggling. I can't figure out how to send these files to the server using Alamofire or any other way.

While googling I found examples of how to send images, mainly one image, which is not quite suitable for my project, also there is **mimeType** you should state, which is not good for 20 different filetypes.
Example:

```
Alamofire.upload(                                     
    multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in
    for (key, value) in parameters {
        multipartFormData.append("\(value)".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: key as String)
    }

    if let data = imageData{
        multipartFormData.append(data, withName: "image", fileName: "image.png", mimeType: "image/png")
    }
```

I have also studied Alamofire documentation and found methods to send files, but I could not make it running. I simply don't understand what should I place after **forResource** and **withExtension**. I tried to place file URL and file extension but it failed to send files.

```
let fileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "video", withExtension: "mov")

Alamofire.upload(                                               
    fileURL, to: serverLink).responseJSON { response in
         debugPrint(response)}
```

I would be grateful if anyone could guide me, or even better provide some code examples.

Sorry for long question, and thank you for your attention and time!

Comment: If you can send an image, you can send any file. Data is data.

Comment: in this case, what should I type after **mimeType**?

Comment: You put whatever mimeType is appropriate for the file in question. There are questions and answers specific to finding the mimeType of a file.

Comment: Ok, I'll give it a go, thanks